# How to display multiple records in jsp using controller in spring?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA1yA.jpg)I have a table of users data which have been retrived below using JdbcTemplate of Spring:

```
List<UserDetailsBean> userdetails = UserDetailsDaoObj.getallUserDataDetails(u.getId());
```

these details needs to be displyed in the jsp so im setting the object **userdetails** as below:

```
modelAndView.addObject("userdetails",userdetails);
```

I'm not able to retrieve the details in JSP the code used in JSP is below:

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${userdetails}"><tr><td>${user.getId()}</td><td>${user.getAddress()}</td><td>${user.getCity()}</td><td>${user.getCountry()}/td></tr></c:forEach>
```

Comment: you must to use forEach in JSP

Comment: i have used for each only below is the code <c:forEach var="user" items="${userdetails}">
       <tr>
        ${user.getId()}${user.getAddress()}${user.getCity()}${user.getCountry()}/td>
       </tr>
       </c:forEach>

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access properties of UserDetails like this

```
<c:out value="${user.id}" />
<c:out value="${user.address}" />
```

assuming that you have standard accessors method present in your class

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this in JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${userdetails}" var="user">
    <tr>
        <td>User ID: <c:out value="${user.id}"/></td>
        <td>User address: <c:out value="${user.address}"/></td>  
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: it is not working even after making changes as u suggested

Comment: how does the UserDetailsBean look like? Edit your answer.

Comment: private int id;
 private String company;
 private String username;
 private String email_address;
 private String first_name;
 private String last_name;
 private String address;
 private String city;
 private String country;
 private int postal_code;
 private String about_me;

Comment: i have getters and setters for this

Comment: Are you sure you are getting any data from the database? Can you do some debugging or logging?

Comment: yes getting data from database but not able to display it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSTL tags to fetch values, In your case it is `<c:out>`.
Also try accessing elements using `field` name and not `getters()`

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${userdetails}">
    <tr>
       <td><c:out value="${user.id}"/></td>
       <td><c:out value="${user.country}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: it is not working even after making changes as u suggested

Comment: @Ashok can you please add your response from server on how it looks?

Comment: private int id;
 private String company;
 private String username;
 private String email_address;
 private String first_name;
 private String last_name;
 private String address;
 private String city;
 private String country;
 private int postal_code;
 private String about_me;

Comment: @Ashok i would like to see response returned from server as well as your complete User pojo.

Comment: i have attached the response  screenshot

Comment: private int id;
 private String company;
 private String username;
 private String email_address;
 private String first_name;
 private String last_name;
 private String address;
 private String city;
 private String country;
 private int postal_code;
 private String about_me;
 
 i have getters and setters for the above

Comment: @Ashok please show us what response (HTTP body) you get back to your jsp that will quickly help us to give you some constructive suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Well from what you posted its not really clear what your issue might be , but an obvious error , is what the others posted in their answers. 
Note that * in order to operate properly , you have to place this line on top of your JSP.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Also the same for the jstl library. It must exist in your classpath.
[link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2)